# Edebug conditional breakpoint when a value that contains a certain string appears?

Tags: debugging, edebug, conditionals

Is it possible to set a [conditional breakpoint](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Breakpoints.html) in edebug such that it gets hit only when a symbol that contains a string "download:" gets hit?

I've tried running `edebug-set-conditional-breakpoint` and when asked for pattern just typed "download:". It set a breakpoint on the line where the cursor was currently positioned, I tried running the function again and nothing happened.